# Is there a way to delineate the parameter of highest influence in a system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, computational-mathematics, parameter-estimation

So I have a system of nonlinear ordinary differential equations dependent on parameters. These equations can traditionally be solved numerically with robust methods and the solution is well defined.

Although the latter satisfies me, I was curious if there was a method, perhaps computationally, to figure out which parameter influences the model the most. I understand this can be defined in many ways, and I am happy with any way of quantification.

Comment: Is the dependence on any of the parameters perturbative, meaning that there is some limit as one or more of the parameters become small or large which is of interest? Is there any bifurcation behavior in your system?

Comment: Maybe if you can provide more information about the structure of your equations, we can help you better.